# How to recover files from a crashed computer?

Tags: boot, data-recovery

I was removing Wine and afterwards everything started going crazy.

The result: I can't boot into Ubuntu nor Windows. I keep getting "Ubuntu boot fail", "Windows boot fail" and finally "Lenovo System Recovery fail" and then I just see the native UEFI menu.

I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu without knowing I can recover my files. Is there any way I can view my files on the partition and save elsewhere them, so I can reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you boot from a live session? That way you can recover your files.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options (larger number means more difficult):

1. Restore your last system back-up then your last data back-up...

OR

2. Boot an Ubuntu live CD and [make a back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc), re-install Windows, then re-install Ubuntu and restore the back-up you just made.

OR

3. Re-install Windows without a back-up and pray to the gods of Micro$oft (Gates & Balmer) that they won't delete any of your Ubuntu data.
   Then re-install Ubuntu and pray to the gods of Ubuntu (Shuttleworth & Torvalds) that they won't delete any of your data anywhere.
   Especially pray to your own god(s) that *you* will not make any mistake yourself on *any* of the steps.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks will try this later today! Praying to tech gods that all goes well

Comment: If you don't *have* a back-up you *should do #2!* **:-)**

Comment: And??? What's the verdict? ;)